# Have client access files from express server: base64 or absolute path to file?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am having a hard time **to pass a .vtt file from my express server to my react client**.
In my express server, I am downloading a subtitle file formated in .srt, I then convert this .srt file to .vtt file, which is the subtitle format that can be read by HTML5.

However, I am wondering what is the best practice to pass this .vtt file to my client. **I could have the .vtt file converted to base64, then pass it to my client as a string, OR I could store the .vtt file in my server, and pass its absolute path to my client.** What is the best solution? And the more efficient in the point of view of storage?

For the latter solution, I have no idea how to do, especially how to grant my client access to a specific folder, let's say */subs/*, located in my backend...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use express static to serve subs folder from your server. Take a look at following commands which will serve subtitles folder at /subs.

```
app.use('/subs', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'path to your subtitle folder')));
```

> The path that you provide to the express.static function is relative
>   to the directory from where you launch your node process. If you run
>   the express app from another directory, it’s safer to use the absolute
>   path of the directory that you want to serve.

[Documentation link](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)